# Is the starting distribution in the solution of DGLAP IR-bare?

Tags: renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

On p.27 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0409313) by John Collins, he says that when defining PDFs in terms of partonic number operators, one acquires an IR-divergent bare PDF (eq. 52). The residue of the IR-divergent term is proportional to the DGLAP splitting kernels:
$$f_{a/b}(\xi,\epsilon)=\delta_{ab}\delta(1-\xi)-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\alpha_s}{\pi}P^{(1)}_{a/b}(\xi)+\mathcal{O}(\alpha^2_s).$$

Now, when we solve the DGLAP equations formally, we find the solution
$$f_i(x,\mu^2)=f_i(x,\mu^2_0)+\sum_j\int^{\mu^2}_{\mu^2_0}d\ln\mu^{\prime2}\int^1_x\frac{dz}{z}P_{ij}(z,\alpha_s(\mu^{\prime2}))f_j(\frac{x}{z},\mu^{\prime2}).$$

Is the $f_i(x,\mu^2_0)$ the same IR-bare PDF from above? Can I see the splitting kernels as a kind of IR counter terms to cancel the remaining IR divergence in the bare PDF?

Comment: Absolutely yes!  The PDF absorbs the IR divergences from the splitting functions so that the total result is finite.  Collins goes through all the details carefully in his book Renormalization.

Comment: @WAH To which pages are you referring to specifically? I have tried to find a section on PDFs or DGLAP in said book but could not find anything on the renormalisation of PDFs.